# Product vs brand ratings and reviews

Tags: ecommerce, conversions, website-review, user-reviews

I have a website selling branded items.

I want to implement ratings and reviews on a product level. Will it help for better conversion if the consumer sees that a brand (that I sell on my website) has good ratings? Or are product ratings and reviews sufficient?

I had a quick look on popular ecommerce websites and no one offers ratings and reviews per brand, only on products.

Comment: I'd go with products as opposed to brands. If people are actively searching for a specific brand, chances are they're already familiar with it, and like it. If they're not familiar with a brand, they'll likely be more interested in ratings/reviews of it's individual products to get an idea of how others like their stuff, as opposed to a rating for the brand overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right I also have not seen much rating and reviews for a brand on e-commerce stores, but what I believe its depend on your business model. Like if your business model is b2b, then rating and review on a brand will be better idea rather than products. If your business model is b2c then you should have to go with rating and review on each of product you have in your store.